# What is the meaning of round circle in er digram

Tags: database, entity-relationship

It has round circle in middle i am not getting the meaning of this circle..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a symbol for inheritance. Financial, physical, and information assets are all kinds of assets.